How can I use the MS Graph api to update a SharePoint site page's titleArea without getting the titleArea duplicated?
When I use the MS Graph api to update the titleArea of a SharePoint site page, the original page banner is unchanged, but I get a new banner showing the changes above it. The new banner has the default image background.

In the example shown I have set the text above the title to show and specified the text to show using the graph api.
I'm using the Mircosoft Graph explorer with the following:
Method:
Patch
URI:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/pages/{page_id}/microsoft.graph.sitepage
Request Headers:
Accept: application/json;odata.medtadata=none
Content-type: application/json
Request Body:
{
   "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.sitePage",
   "title": "Very Important News",
   "titleArea": {
       "showTextBlockAboveTitle": true,
       "textAboveTitle": "Archived - Published Date 01/01/2020"
   }
}

